# Busy Indicator in react native

Tags: android, react-native, busyindicator

I am creating ToDo Application using react-native in android. For CRUD operations I am using the database. Now, when I am making db requests I am showing busy indicator till my request gets completed and set state with same. But my problem is that loder is shown at bottom most layer (like Below my tasks),instead of showing above tasks as usual. I tried using ZIndex also but it's not working.

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBDut.png)

Any help will be appericiated.
Thank You..!!

Comment: Can you please add the code here instead of image?

Comment: you should either show the busy indicator or the content. I'm wondering if you are trying to achieve  both(something like a youtube video loading)

Answer (score 2):

You can overlay the busy indicator over your page using the right styles..

```
<View style={styles.indicator}>
  <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.loading} size="small"/>
</View>

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  indicator: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  }
})
```